# AlertDialog within an element of an Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-alertdialog

I have the following question, results that I have an adapter class
In which it shows a list of elements (which may have photographs)

Examples

- Array [0] Contains a photo
- Array [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGvJi.png) Does not contain a photo
- Array [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWy3X.png) Contains a photo

My question is how can I display aDialog alert inside Array [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGvJi.png)?

He tried, set the alertDialog, but it is always placed twice inside the Array in the position [0]
I just wish I could display theDialog alert at the Array position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGvJi.png)

Could anyone help me please.

```
displayImage = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
```

final ChatMessage myMessage = pathsLocal.get(position);

```
        AttachmentObject attachmentObject = null;
        switch (myMessage.getMessageType()) {
            case IMAGE:
                attachmentObject = myMessage.getFullsizePhoto();
                break;
            case VIDEO:
                attachmentObject = myMessage.getAttachment("video");
                break;
        }

            File fileImage = new File(attachmentObject.localPath);

            if (fileImage.exists()) {
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fileImage);

                Picasso.with(ApplicationSingleton.getInstance())
                        .load(uri)
                        .into(displayImage);
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityAdapter);
                alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.title);
                alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.subtitle);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialogBuilder1 = alertDialog.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
```

What I am trying to do is just an AlertDialog entry within position 1 without affecting element 0 and 2 of the viewPager

[image]

[image]
[image]

I'm just trying to add an AlertDialog to position 1 of the viewPager element

Comment: do you want to filter out all photos and only execute a certain task on non-photo objects? sorry your question is not that specific

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Please explain your question in detail

Comment: Is it single fragment with multiple Images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create or show your `AlertDialog`s when creating the `ViewPager` pages, instead you should check if you need an `AlertDialog` when a page is selected, and then build and show the dialog, using [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) or [ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html)

```
myViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
   void onPageSelected(int position) {
      boolean shouldIShowAlert = // implement this
      if (shouldIShowAlert) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityAdapter);
                alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.title);
                alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.subtitle);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialogBuilder1 = alertDialog.create();
                alertDialog.show();
      }
   }
});
```